# $\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a+r\exp i\theta)|\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a)|\,d\theta$ implies the two integrands are equal for all $\theta$ - why?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification

When [this](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Erichardt/414/414-ch3.pdf) proof of the maximum modulus principle (if you scroll down a bit) writes (for a holomorphic $f$):

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a+r\exp i\theta)|\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a)|\,\mathrm{d}\theta\implies|f(a)|=|f(a+r\exp i\theta)|,\,\forall\theta$$

"Because $|f(a+r\exp i\theta)|$ is a continuous function in $\theta$", aren't they very, very wrong? Unless there's something specific about this case, we only have equality if I could obtain the same answer using *any* bounds on the integral, but we are here stuck on the bounds $0,\,2\pi$. As far as I know, the mean value theorem guarantees only that we have $|f(a)|=|f(a+r\exp i\theta)|$ for *some particular $\theta$*.

This equality that they draw is very important to their proof (they use the same logic elsewhere) but I don't see how it holds. I could take for example $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\theta)\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\theta)\,d\theta$, but $\sin\neq\cos$ in general.

What about the modulus function, or perhaps the $r\exp i\theta$ offset, allows them to make this claim? It isn't justified properly at all in the text, in my view.

Comment: but here you know that $|f(a)| \ge |f(z)|$, so that $|f(a)|  - |f(a+r\exp(i\theta))| \ge 0$. Applying linearity of integrals, you arrive at $0 = \int_0^{2\pi} |f(a)| - |f(a+r\exp(i\theta))| d\theta $. Since integrand is non-negative this implies $|f(a)| - |f(a+r\exp(i\theta))| = 0$ for almost every $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, but then, since $f$ is holomorphic, it is also continuous, so the equality above must hold for every $\theta$ (for example because the set of full Lebesgue measure in $[0,2\pi]$ must be dense in $[0,2\pi]$).

Comment: @DominikKutek Thank you! I was stuck worrying that I was missing some general result, rather than a specific case